# In Browser Javascript Syntax Checking

Tags: javascript, web-browser, ide

I am wondering if there is any javascript libraries out there that allow for in browser Javascript or CSS checking.

I don't need something with intellisense or debugging etc. 
Im just looking for something that would allow me to write in a textarea element a chunk of javascript or css that would underline things like incorrect use of semi-colons and other generic bugs. Colouring and line formatting would also be useful.

Thanks,

Comment: Your requirements are pretty thin.  But, have you looked at the FireFox Developer Tools?  In particular, the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)?

Comment: Yeah I have used the browser tools and things like greasemonkey too. I was more hoping for something inside the browser as my comanys product allows the user which is thousands of people to add their own javascript and css to be rendered by placing it in a textarea element in the config settings. There is a lot of complaints (even I find it annoying) from trying to write natively inside it. I always pull it away into vs and then copy it back across when im happy. Trying to remove that step.